# httpd.conf new file locations -apache2

Tags: apache2

I'm trying to add some semblance of security for my website. I've been following this: https://www.tecmint.com/apache-security-tips/ and they want me to edit the httpd file but it doesn't exist in my server. I started doing some more research and I found this https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/httpd.html which says it doesn't exist and "all configuration options have been moved to the below referenced directories".  So I would appreciate it if someone could tell me which files to add those options to! Also should I edit the apache2.conf file?
Edit: I'm using ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Comment: which operating system you are using?

Comment: Man I totally forgot! Sorry I'm new to asking questions but I'm using ubuntu 18.03 LTS

Answer (score 7, accepted):

the Main Configuration file for `RHEL/CentOS/Fedora` is: `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf`
and for `Debian/Ubuntu` is:  `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`.

as you are using `ubuntu os`  so you should edit `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`.

for more information and the history about `apache2.conf` and `httpd.conf` , as mentioned within ubuntu doc [Ubuntu 18.04 Apache2 Web Server Guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/httpd.html):

> httpd.conf: historically the main Apache2 configuration file, named
>   after the httpd daemon. Now the file does not exist. In older versions
>   of Ubuntu, the file might be present, but empty, as all configuration
>   options have been moved to the below-referenced directories.

Comment: So I should just edit the apache2.conf file for all those commands?

Comment: yes, if you want to edit the global configuration of your server, then you should edit it. please if the answer helped you validate it, in that way it may can help someone else